# sum values in an array for all values less than current

Tags: python, numpy

Looking to find a way without looping to get all values in the same interval that are less than the current value but are also within a defined interval.

I have 8760 rows of data to sort and was hoping there was a shorter way other than looping. With some looping code, it takes over 5 mins to execute

```
x=np.array([[250,1,1],[300,.5,1],[100,2,1],[200,.75,1],[150,.25,1],[50,.5,2]])
```

I am trying to sum the first element `(250,300,100,50)` where the second element is less than the current value and the third element is equal to the third element of the current value.

example

for 
`[250,1,1]`

I want to just find `300+200+150` since they  have `1` as the third element and the second elements of `.5` and `.75` and `.25` are less than 1.  This needs to continue for each row

for the second element `[300,.5,1]` it would find one value of `150`, since that is the only one with a greater index, has `1` as the third element and has a value of less than `.5`.

edit: fixed minimal example

Comment: Should the sum exclude the current value in `x[:,0]`? Your example isn't totally clear to me; I think it doesn't agree with the description given above. And a general note: maybe this question is better suited for CodeReview?

Comment: it should not include the current value.

Answer (score 0):

May be use Boolean masking?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[250,1,1],[300,.5,1],[100,2,1],[200,.75,1],[150,.25,1],[50,.5,2]])

mask = (x[:, 1] < x[:, 0]) & (x[:, 2] == np.floor_divide(x[:, 0], 100))
np.sum(x[mask, 0])
```

Comment: that just gives `250` - if I get the question correctly, he want's to calculate this sum for each row

Comment: He can use `np.cumsum` or any other function that reflects the exact computations he wants. It is just an example but the key point is that if he is able to use masking then he does not need to use a loop and will be quicker.

Comment: Sure, and I also think masking could be a good approach - it's just that the mask would be different depending on each row (still, if I get the question right). So maybe you could show how this would avoid looping?

Comment: I am stuck here - newarray=np.where((a[:,2]==1) & (a[:,2]<=a[0,2])).  In the line with a[0,2] , the zero is just substituted in a loop for the current number in the loop. how do I get the current index of the item in the array and then sum the results a[newarray]?